# Bigquery AllowLageResults and setMaxResults

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Instead of setting AllowLargeResults true for job in bigquery, can we use setMaxresults property to get response in pages or we still need to set AllowLargeResults even if we have set the setMaxresults and getting response in pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query result is "large" (hundreds of megabytes), then you will need to use allowLargeResults regardless of whether you read it later in pages or not. Otherwise the query will fail.